# Sum Max values of a group By

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have this query, that produces next result

```
$result = DB::table('contagenshora')
            ->select(DB::raw('post_id as post_id'), DB::raw('product_id'), DB::raw('max(val) as maxHour'), DB::raw('hour'))
            ->whereBetween('date', array($dt->toDateTimeString(), $dt2->toDateTimeString()))
            ->where('hour', '=', $actHour->hour)
            ->groupBy(DB::raw('post_id'), DB::raw('product_id'))
            ->get();
```

Result: `Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [post_id] => 1 [product_id] => 1 [maxHour] => 4 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [post_id] => 1 [product_id] => 2 [maxHour] => 3 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [post_id] => 4 [product_id] => 0 [maxHour] => 6 ) ) )`

Now, I need the sum of "maxHour", but grouped by "post_id", I need something like this:

(For example, for post_id = 1, I need the sum of 4+3)

Result: `Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [post_id] => 1 [maxHour] => 7 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [post_id] => 4 [maxHour] => 6 ) ) )`

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `product_id` from `group by` clause and `select` then. Also no need to use `DB::raw()` for direct selectable columns.

```
$result = DB::table('contagenshora')
            ->select('post_id', DB::raw('max(val) as maxHour'))
            ->whereBetween('date', array($dt->toDateTimeString(), $dt2->toDateTimeString()))
            ->where('hour', $actHour->hour)
            ->groupBy('post_id')
            ->get();
```

Comment: And if I need to group by hour too? So I have the maxHour for each post and each hour. And I want sum all hours group by post. Can you help me?

Comment: You are passing `hour` to the where clause. So for that particular entry, the results will be shown. Btw, try your own first.